# When do I need to restart database server in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

I was wondering in which cases do I need to restart the database server in Django on production. Whether it is Postgres/MySQL, I was just thinking do we need to restart the database server at all. If we need to restart it, when and why do we need to restart the server?

Any explanation would be really helpful, Cheers!

Comment: This question is too general. There are a thousand things which can go wrong and will go wrong. You never even know if a restart helps. But just from a Django point of view, you would never need to restart your postgres server if everything works well (which I already mentioned is never the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really ever need to restart the database server.

You probably do need to restart - or at least reload - the *web* server whenever any of the code changes. But the db is a separate process, and shouldn't need to be restarted.

Answer (score 2):

You will not NEED to restart your database in production due to anything you've done in Django. You may need to restart it to change your database security or configuration settings, but that has nothing to do with Django and in a lot of cases doesn't even need a restart.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when the settings that are controlling the application are changed then the server has to be restarted.